# get value of individual cell using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I thought this would have been a pretty simple task, but it is turning out to be much more complicated than I thought it would be. Trying to read a simple excel spreadsheet with a table of values, then will perform calculations on the values and output a new sheet.

First question is, what library do people recommend to use? Pandas? Openpyxl? Currently using openpyxl and struggling to get the value of an individual cell. Here's some code:

```
    collectionOrder = np.empty( [numRows,2], dtype='object')
numCountries = 0
for i in burndownData.iter_rows():
    elemnt = burndownData.cell(row=i,column=1)
    print("elemnt=",elemnt.value )
    if not( np.isnan(burndownData.cell(row=i,column=1).value)):
        collectionOrder[ int(burndownData.cell(row=i,column=1).value) ][0] = burndownData.cell(row=i,column=1).value
        collectionOrder[ int(burndownData.cell(row=i,column=1).value) ][1] = i
        numCountries = numCountries + 1
```

But when I first try and use the cell reference, (burndownData.cell(row=i,column=1)), I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int' 
File "C:\Users\cpeddie\Documents\projects\generateBurndownReport.py", line 59, in run elemnt = 
burndownData.cell(row=i,column=1) File 
"C:\Users\cpeddie\Documents\projects\generateBurndownReport.py", line 96, in <module>
run()
```

Everything I have seen on the web says this is the way to get the value of an individual cell. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way?

Thanks....

Comment: Why are you using both .iter_rows() and .cell()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're doing something more complicated than gathering some cells, `numpy` or `pandas` is usually unnecessary overhead. `openpyxl` works well enough on its own.

You have two options for iterating through a worksheet but you're trying to mix them, hence the error.

One option is simply query every cell's value using the `cell` method of the worksheet object with the `row` and `column` keyword arguments. The `row` and `column` indexes are 1-based integers, like this:

`burndownData.cell(row=1, column=1).value`

The other option is iterating the sheet and indexing the row as a list:

```
for row in burndownData.iter_rows():
    elemnt = row[0].value
```

This will get you column A of row 1, column A of row 2, and so on. (because it's an index of a Python `list` it's zero-based)

What you were doing above:

```
for i in burndownData.iter_rows():
    elemnt = burndownData.cell(row=i,column=1)
```

generates an error because `i` is a tuple of openpyxl `Cell` objects, and the `row` argument to `cell` expects an integer.

**Update**: I should add there's a third way to reference cells using the spreadsheet `column:row` syntax, like this:

```
burndownData['B9'].value
```

but unless you're only going to select a few specific cells, translating back and forth between letters and numbers seems clumsy.

Comment: What a great explanation! Thanks, I didn't get this distinction at all from the documentation I could find.

Comment: For completeness, I revised my answer with a third method but it sounds like you have what you need.